# passing parameters while sending mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-email

i got a task to build leave management application in asp.net c#, in leave application when employee fills the required details and press apply button, a mail should deliver to respective manager saying

"Hello {Manager},

{LoggedInUser}has requested {TypeofLeave} for {NumofDays} kindly login to the portal to accept or reject it

Thank You."

I am able to get the mail but what i need is in place of {Manager},{TypeoLeave},{NumofDays}, and {LoggedInUser} i need respective name of manager,logged in user and which type o leave the employee has applied and for what number of days. It should extract from database.

For eg:"Hello ABC,

XYZ has requested Sick Leave for 5 days kindly login to the portal to accept or reject it

Thank You."

Right now I am getting tsame structure as above.

Please help me.

```
protected void BtnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MTMSDTO objc = new MTMSDTO();

        int Flag = 0;

        LblLogdInUser.Text = Session["EmpName"].ToString();
        objc.LoggedInUser = LblLogdInUser.Text;
        objc.TypeofLeave = DrpTypeofLeave.SelectedItem.Text;

        string date;
        date = Convert.ToDateTime(TxtBeginDate.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

        objc.BeginDate = dt;
        objc.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(TxtEndDate.Text);
        objc.Description = TxtDescription.Text;
        objc.NumofDays = Convert.ToInt32(TxtNumofDays.Text);
        //objc.EmpName = LblLogdInUser.Text;
        objc.Status = TxtStatus.Text;


        int X = obj.InsertLeave(objc);
        {
            if (X >= 0)
            {
                Flag = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Flag = 0;
            }
        }

        if (Flag == 1)
        {
            LblSuccess.Visible = true;
            LblSuccess.Text = "Data Added Successfully and Leave Application Succesfully Sent";
            DrpTypeofLeave.ClearSelection();
            TxtBeginDate.Text = "";
            TxtEndDate.Text = "";
            TxtDescription.Text = "";
            TxtNumofDays.Text = "";
            TxtStatus.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            LblErr.Visible = true;
            LblErr.Text = "Failed To Add Data and Send Leave Request!!!";
        }

        objc.EmpName = Convert.ToString(Session["EmpName"]);
        DataSet GrdLH = obj.GrdLeaveHistory(objc);
        DataView GrdLeaveH = new DataView();
        GrdLeaveH.Table = GrdLH.Tables[0];
        GridViewLeaveHistory.DataSource = GrdLeaveH;
        GridViewLeaveHistory.DataBind();


        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add("abcer@abc.in");
        message.Subject = "Leave Request";
        message.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com");
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        message.Body = "<span style = font-family:Arial,font-size:10pt>";
        message.Body += "Hello <b>{Manager}</b>,<br /><br />";
        message.Body += "{LoggedInUser}has requested {TypeofLeave} for {NumofDays}"; 
        message.Body += "kindly login to the portal to accept or reject it";
        message.Body += "<br />";
        message.Body += "<br />";
        message.Body += "Thank You.<br />";
        message.Body += "</span>";
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("");
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
```

Comment: Well where are you replacing the placeholders ?

Comment: why dont you just create variables - give them the values and use them in the message.body string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to the following:[Make sure you have the manager name, logged in username, type of leave and NoOfDays are stored in the session or whatever you like, but change the variables accordingly]

```
  message.Body += "Hello <b>"+Session["Manager"].ToString()+"</b>,<br /><br />";
  message.Body += Session["LoggedInUser"].ToString()+"has requested"+
                  Session["TypeOfLeave"].ToString()+"for "+Session["NoOfDays"].ToString()+
  mesaage.Body += "kindly login to the portal to accept or reject it";
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating html template at the run time, We can define a template in text or html file with all the place holder (Like {ManagerName}, {RequestedUser}). At the time of sending mail, we can give Dictionary with key as {ManagerName}, {RequestedUser} and value as their respective value from database. Now read the file and then we can iterate on keys of Dictionary and replace keys with their values in template. After doing these operation we have created message body.

Comment: i got that option too .. i hav an html file which has same place holders... but dnt no how to pass values to it

Comment: You can read the file and have value in string.                  string fileContent = File.ReadAllText("file path");                                          And after that do string replace operation.                           Foreach(var item in dictPlaceHolder)                                   
{
    fileContent = fileContent.replace(item.key, item.value);
}